# SQL Query Best Practice to Generate A Percentage Table of 1 Time buyer buyers Versus Frequent Buyers

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have a table called `client` which is as follows:

```
Client Price
============
A      123
A      389
A      34
B      4
B      5
C      33
```

For instance, it means that Client A bought in our shop 3 times [first time for 123$ second for 389$, third for 34$]. Sames logic for other clients...

I try to get a percentage table to get the Client who bought 1 time only and the one who bought more than 1 time. The result should be

```
Category    Percentage
=======================
1timebuyer  0.3333
2timeOrMore 0.66666
```

Indeed the client A bought 3 times and client B 2 times, so there is 2 out of 3 client who belong to the 2timeOrMore category. Hence 2timeOrMore represent 0.6666 [2/3] of the buyers and 1timebuyer 0.3333 [1/3]

What is the most optimal way to do this in mysql **in 1 SQL query only** ?

Comment: I am seeing 1/3 and 2/3 for the data you provide, not 0.5 and 0.5.  Your table also has a suspicious name.  The `clients` table should have one row per *client*.  You seem to have a sales or transactions table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are totally right. I tried to modify before someone see but you were faster... Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two levels of aggregation.  The inner one is:

```
select client, count(*) as cnt
from clients c
group by client;
```

I would then pivot all the counts like this:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(client), max(client)
from (select client, count(*) as cnt
      from clients c
      group by client
     ) c
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

But you want something simpler:

```
select (case when cnt = 1 then '1' else '>1' end) as grp,
       count(*) as num_clients,
       count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from (select client, count(*) as cnt
      from clients c
      group by client
     ) c
group by grp;
order by cnt;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer [regarding last query] I just have, with mysql, issue with the line count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio it says : 3 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "ratio" at position 148)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 147)
Unexpected token. (near "ratio" at position 148)

Comment: @S12000 . . . You are probably using an old version of MySQL that does not support window functions.

Comment: yes you are right. This is the issue. Thanks for your help